# Flutter : timestamp of incoming SMS is wrong using telephony package

Tags: flutter, timestamp, sms, telephony

I am developing a SMS app in flutter using telephony package. In this app, app is listening an incoming messages and doing some processing on it. After processing, I want to store some unique identifier for this particular SMS in local database so that when I have to display this message to user with processed result, I can use this ID from local database and filter SMS from Inbox. I tried following few logic but it did not work :

1- smsID from Inbox to local DB but it is not reliable as if particular message is deleted from inbox, new incoming sms get same smsID as deleted one.

2- (time stamp and address) of incoming sms but the problem is that I am getting the timestamp of incoming sms with around 1 second less than what I am getting from Inbox. e.g the actual time stamp is 12:10:32 in inbox but in the case of receiving incoming sms, it is 12:10:31. I don't know what is the problem.

Please help me find a solution for this.

Comment: have you tried askign for help on the package [github issue section](https://github.com/shounakmulay/Telephony/issues)?

Comment: Not yet. I will ask there too. Whatever will be update, I'll post over here.